# Update portion of page using Ajax without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax

The page is mostly in PHP and only lightly uses any JavaScript, so I do not wish to use jQuery when it must be possible without it. I want to update a portion of a page, but I'm not very experienced with Ajax. jQuery's method was to use the page's URL with "#sectionid" after it.

Comment: You probably don't want to hear it, but just use jQuery. If you're worried about page weight, just use a CDN'ed copy of jQuery. The likelihood, if you do, is that your clients will already have jQuery cached.

Comment: Jquery is javascript. It's nothing more than javascript libraries, so you aren't breaking your rules by using it.

Comment: I know that jQuery is JavaScript. I only need one very small piece of it, and thus do not want to load superfluous libraries.

Comment: @HackedByChinese is right, it will most likely take less time to for the user's browser to retrieve a `304 Not Modified` answer from Google or Microsoft's CDN and running your JQuery code than loading your non-jquery code. Regardless of that, if you still want to do it the hard way, you should take a read on a good [AJAX tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp), then all you have to do is use the html response text inside of the callback function  `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)`, which will be demonstrated a couple pages after the tutorial's introduction.

Comment: Seeing as most people will try to crucify me for linking to W3S, I'll recommend [this tutorial](http://www.xul.fr/en-xml-ajax.html) which is linked from Mozilla, faster and more direct to the point as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the information you'd need to know to hand-roll your own is here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest

You'll be interested in the `send`, `open`, `response`, `readyState` and `onreadystatechange` sections of the documentation.

`onreadystatechange` will fire whenever the readyState of your request changes.  Once your `readyState` has changed to `done` you can check the response you received.

Make sure when you open you open in async mode.  You don't want to freeze your page by making synchronous http requests.

if you need it running on older versions of I.E. wikipedia has some good information:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Support_in_Internet_Explorer_versions_5.2C_5.5_and_6

I assume you know how to use `document.getElementById` and `element.innerHTML` to set the content of your element.

---

**EDIT**
Went ahead and added a basic implementation:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// IE7+, Firefox, Webkit, Opera
  window.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {// IE6, 5
  window.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("someId").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "pageUrl", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```