# refreshing specific div using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm totally new to AJAX, so I'm sorry if the question turned out to be too stupid or anything.

Alright then, here goes...

---

assuming that `http://example.com/index.php` file have the following content:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>Ajax Test</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<!-- Other contents which don't need to change -->

<a class="puke" href="#">Button</a>

<div class="rainbow"><?php echo mt_rand(0,100); ?></div>

<!-- Other contents which don't need to change -->

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I want to make it so that whenever `a.puke` is clicked, only the content of `div.rainbow` will get refreshed.

How can I achieve such result?

thank you.

Comment: can you add more code? What is your ajax code doing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678232/update-portion-of-page-using-ajax-without-jquery

Comment: You want to load new data into `div.rainbow` but what data and from where you want to pull the data ?

Comment: the simple php inside div.rainbow should be generating different content each time it gets refreshed. that's my aim.

but I think refreshing the whole page just for it is just too much.

Comment: Different content from where ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your are new to AJAX, here is the code example for ajax and php- [ajax php](http://simpletutorials.com/?path=tutorials/javascript/simple_ajax) . Refer this link

```
       $.ajax({
          url: "http://example.com/index.php", 
          type: "GET",        
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){                          
              $("div.rainbow").html(data);                   
          }           
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .responseText

```
document.getElementsByClassName("puke").onclick = updateDiv();

function updateDiv() {

    upd=new XMLHttpRequest();
    upd.open("GET","test.php?action=something" ,  false);
    upd.send();
    console.log(upd.responseText);
    document.getElementsByClassName("rainbow").innerHTML=upd.responseText;
}
```

this is how you get contents of test.php?action=something and put it to

```
div.rainbow
```